# Sending bulk messages in twillo notify API via CURL (php)

Tags: php, api, curl, twilio, notify

```php
$data = [];
    $data['ToBinding'] =  json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19991112222"));
    $data['Body'] ="test";
    $ch = curl_init("https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $resultData = curl_exec($ch);
```

This code was copied from another post.  I am able to get this to work just fine, using real numbers of course.  However I cannot populate $data['ToBinding'] with multiple numbers, which is the whole purpose of using Twilio **Notify**.  I have tried many different combinations of code and it blows up, most of the time with "Cannot convert incoming parameters to notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid".

I was able to get it to at least execute without errors using this code (real numbers of course):

```php
$data['ToBinding'] =  json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19991112222","binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19993334444"));
```

But it only sends to the first number in the array.  Any help on how to populate the array to send to multiple numbers (or maybe another way using cURL) will be appreciated.

====  FULL CODE ====

```
$query = array("ToBinding" => array(
json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19991112222")),
json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19993334444"))
));
$data = http_build_query($query);
$data = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/simU', '', $data);
echo $data;
$data['Body'] ="Notify cURL API test";
$ch = curl_init("https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/<NOTIFY ID HERE >/Notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'<ACCT ID HERE>:<TOKEN HERE >');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resultData = curl_exec($ch);
```

=====  FINAL WORKING CODE  =====

```
$data['Body'] ="Notify cURL API test";
$data['ToBinding'] = array(
   json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms","address"=>"+19191112222")),
   json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms","address"=>"+19193334444"))
);

$query = http_build_query($data);
$string = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '=', $query);
$ch = curl_init("https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/ISxxxxxxxxxx/Notifications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'ACxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resultData = curl_exec($ch);

echo "curl Response=".$resultData."<br>";
$responseHttp = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `ToBinding` parameter is an array of binding objects. Notify implements support for that by decoding multiple `ToBinding` parameters from the request.

The [curl example from the Notify documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource?code-sample=code-send-a-notification-to-bindings-in-the-request-1&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) looks like this:

```
curl -X POST https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Notifications \
    --data-urlencode 'ToBinding={"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+15555555555"}' \
    --data-urlencode 'ToBinding={"binding_type":"facebook-messenger", "address":"123456789123"}' \
    -d 'Body=Hello Bob' \
    -u 'your_account_sid:your_auth_token'
```

As you can see, there are two `ToBinding` parameters included in the data.

As far as I can tell, PHP doesn't support building the body like that. [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) appears to be useful, but builds arrays of data using `name[index]` form, which we don't want. You can strip the `[index]` out though, with something like the following:

```php
$query = array("ToBinding" => array(
  json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19991112222")),
  json_encode(array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19993334444"))
));
$data = http_build_query($query);
$data = preg_replace('/%5B[0-9]+%5D/simU', '', $data);
echo $data;
# => ToBinding=%7B%22binding_type%22%3A%22sms%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22%2B19991112222%22%7D&ToBinding=%7B%22binding_type%22%3A%22sms%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22%2B19993334444%22%7D
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: philnash:  It did not work.  I get the error:  "At least one parameter among Identity, Tag, and ToBinding must be specified"  So I tried other combinations such as:  $query = array(  
  array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19192915100"),  
  array("binding_type"=>"sms", "address"=>"+19192915100")  
);  
$data['ToBinding'] = json_encode($query);  And I get the message: Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid",  (Not sure how to put in line breaks.  HELP says to end the line with 2 spaces and it will br but it doesn't work

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [the Twilio PHP library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) for this? [It should make it easier](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource?code-sample=code-send-a-notification-to-bindings-in-the-request-1&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x).

Comment: The main reason we strongly prefer cURL is because with cURL we get back Status Codes for ALL API calls, successful (2xx)  and errors (3xx, 4xx).  With the Twilio Helper Libraries / SDK it throws exceptions for errors so we're coding a series of try / catch blocks, and we don't even know what we'll get back.   We might get back a string “[HTTP 400] Unable to create record:" and we need to parse the string for the error codes and messages or we might get "Unknown subresource notification" with no status code.  With cURL we ALWAYS know what the status is.  Not so much with the Twilio SDK.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. So what we are trying to achieve here is a request where the body contains a `ToBinding` option for each JSON encoded binding (where a binding is a `binding_type` and an `address`). That's what I tried to do in my answer, can you put together my code and the rest of the request that you are using and add it to your question along with the current error you get back and we can try to work from there.

Comment: Thank you philnash.  Full code shown in the original question.  The error I get back is:  Response={"code": 20001, "message": "At least one parameter among Identity, Tag, and ToBinding must be specified", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001", "status": 400}

Comment: philnash - see =====  FINAL WORKING CODE ===== in my original post.  That works.  It is much like you described earlier, but I think I had some coding errors and some code in the wrong place in the script.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end!